# How to get the content after a string using regex in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a string as follows:

```
A5697[2:10] = {ravi, rageev, raghav, smith};
```

I want the content after "A5697[2:10] =". So, my output should be:

```
{ravi, rageev, raghav, smith};
```

This is my code:

```
print(re.search(r'(?<=A\d+\[.*\] =\s).*', line).group())
```

But, this is giving **error**:

> sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Can anyone help to solve this issue? I would prefer to use regex.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `s.split(' = ')[1]`?

Comment: This string is in file and it is having some other lines also with '='. If I use split it would add those also. It would be better if you can provide the solution with regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can try re.sub , like below, Since you have given only one data point. I am assuming all the other data points are following the similar pattern.

```
import re 
text = "A5697[2:10] = {ravi, rageev, raghav, smith}"
re.sub(r'(A\d+\[\d+:\d+\]\s+=\s+)(.+)', r'\2', text)
```

returns,

```
'{ravi, rageev, raghav, smith}'
```

`re.sub` : substitutes the entire match as given as regex with the 2nd capturing group. The second capturing group captures every thing after '= '.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the bits you don't want:

```
print re.sub(r'A\d[^=]*= *','',line)
```

See demo here: https://rextester.com/NSG17655